# Labview: Stop a While Loop On Completion of a VI Outside of Loop

Tags: while-loop, labview

I am calling the System Exec VI and in parallel would like a while loop to do a task repeatedly until the System Exec VI finishes, but I have not found a way for a while loop to either start before receiving all inputs, or be able to change an input's value after execution (through shift registers, etc) correctly for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please, decribe what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I call System Exec, it calls a python script that transfers files between a two servers. The python script finishes when either an error is raised or there are no files left. In the while loop in Labview, I want to see how many files are left and display a progress bar for % files uploaded. The only guarantee I have is that the System Exec VI finishes. However there is no way to have the output of System Exec stop the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options for communicating between parallel sections of code. My suggestion would be either a notifier (and you do your repetitive task when the wait times out) or an event structure (same idea - you do the repetitive task in the timeout event and you trigger the completion event with the data you get back from the System Exec VI, which then also stops the loop).

Note that in any case, the System Exec VI will only give you the output after it was done, so there's no way of knowing how much progress was made, unless your repetitive task involves looking at the number of files.